# How to setup epsilon in K-Means in new Spark ml library

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

In spark.mllib library, KMeans has function to set epsilon parameter when building Kmeans instance.

But I did not see any function in Kmeans new Spark.ml library to setup this parameter. The reason I am asking is because the number of cluster the new KMeans generate is less than what I specified in setK() method, so I want to increase the number of clusters generated by decreasing epsilon a bit.

Does anyone know how to setup epsilon in new Spark.ml Kmeans class?

`org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epsilon in the `spark.ml` library has been renamed to `tol` (short for tolerance)

Example:

```
KMeans kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1L).setTol(0.0001)
KMeansModel model = kmeans.fit(dataset);
```